# c++ - How can i initialize a smart point using a naked new?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

I am trying to learn the new c++ standard but I am coming up short when using the smart pointers.
Here is the code for a program I am writing that does not want to work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template <typename T> class printer
{
public:
    printer(T val)
    {
       value = val;
    }

    void printvalue()
    {
        std::cout << "The value is " << val;
        std::cin.get();
    }


 private:
    T value;
 };

template <typename T> class test
{
public:
    test(T value)
    {
            printer<T> * test = new printer<T>(value);
            *printValue = test;
    }

    void beginTest()
    {
            printValue.get()->printvalue();
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<printer<T>> printValue;
};
```

I wrote the main function like this:

```
int main()
{
    test<int> t(5);
    t.beginTest();
    return 0;
}
```

after I complile I get the following error:
binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'printer *' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

this refers to this line of code:
   *printValue = test;

I thought new was suppose to work even in this scenario, no I can overload the operator I suppose but I am sure that there is something I am missing

Note: I am using the visual studio 2013 compiler

Please help

Comment: You never define `printValue`.

Comment: `*printValue` has type `printer<T>`. You don't want to assign to that, do you?

Comment: @n.m. It's defined at the very bottom of the code.

Comment: @n.m. Inline member function bodies have full access to all members of the class, even those defined afterwards. `struct S { void f() { i = 3; } int i; };` is correctly accepted by all major compilers.

Comment: Ah, this is a class member. I didn't see that. See what happens when you don't indent your code?

Comment: @n.m. (To clarify, I'm not the OP.) The code did have sensible indentation already in the markdown, but it didn't show up as intended for reasons not entirely clear to me.

Comment: @hwd I have just fixed that (the text used real tabs which got collapsed by the markdown).

Comment: Ah, the web: an unfortunate _but extremely rare_ justifiable counter-argument for tab indentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either pass the pointer directly to the `std::unique_ptr` construtor:

```
test(T value)
  : printValue(new printer<T>(value))
{ }
```

Or you can call `reset` on the `std::unique_ptr`:

```
test(T value)
{
    printValue.reset(new printer<T>(value));
}
```

Note that you do not need to use `get()` to access the object that the `unique_ptr` points at - you can treat it just like a normal pointer:

```
printValue->printvalue();
```

Answer (score 1):

The method to replace a pointer in a existing unique_ptr is `reset` :

```
printValue.reset( new printer<T>( value ) );
```

The C++14 revision will add a better syntax with `make_unique`, it is already part of VS2013 :

```
printValue = std::make_unique<printer<T>>( value );
```