# How do i free up memory occupied by a tree?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, tree

Each node in my tree has M children. Some of them may be NULL. After I get done with the tree I am recursively going through each element of the tree and deleting it but that does not free up memory used by the program. First I tried this without defining destructor and then after defining destructor too doesn't help. Please tell me where I am wrong in freeing up memory space. My code for deleting tree is as follows:-

```
void deleteTree(node* s)
{
    if(s==NULL)
        return ;
    else
    {
        for (int i=0 ; i < M ; i++)
        {
            deleteTree(s->child[i]);
        }
        delete(s);
    }
}
```

A node contains a string vector ,array of integers and array of pointers to its children.

```
struct node 
{
    vector<string> stateBoard;
    int Nstate;
    int *NstateAction;
    node** child;
    int depth;
    double Q;
    double *Qvalue;

    node()
    {
        Nstate=0;
        depth = 0;
        NstateAction = new int[M];
        Qvalue = new double[M];
        child = new node *[M];                          //
        for( int i=0 ; i < M ; i++)
        {
            NstateAction[i] = 0;
            child[i]=NULL;
        }
    }
    ~node()
    {
        stateBoard.clear();
        vector<string>(stateBoard).swap(stateBoard);
    }
};
```

Comment: Use `delete[]` on everything you've created with `new[]`. And you need a copy constructor and assignment operator for your struct.

Comment: I am not copying anywhere, so why do i need a copy constructor then?

Comment: For delete[] , i replaced the for loop with delete[] s->child; but even that does not free up space.

Comment: If you don't copy anywhere - then prohibit copying so that you can't accidentally write the code that attempts copying.

Comment: You need a copy constructor of your own. Otherwise the compiler will generate one, which may not be to your liking, and call it in places you don't expect it to, ditto. If you really think you aren't copying, declare it but don't define it, or delete it (C++11).

Comment: Okay. i will do that but does that has any relation to the deleteTree method not being able to free up memory ?

Comment: @Anand I've told you why you're leaking memory. Are you reading this thread? Or am I just wasting my time here?

Comment: yes. I declared a copy constructor and left it undefined as suggested by you but still It is unable to free memory.

Comment: @Anand This is incredible. [Please follow this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23125930/207421). You aren't paying any attention whatsoever.

Comment: I think I got confused. delete doesn't free up memory space. It just marks it as available. And to check memory status I was looking at System manager ( in Ubuntu). So even after the tree getting deleted memory usage was not coming down and that made me think that tree is still not deleted. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Anand The delete operator invokes destructors and frees memory. However it doesn't release it back the operating system, if that's your concern. Nothing does that except system-specific APIs that are rarely invoked. You need to make it clear whether you've actually read those things down there. They're called 'answers'.

Comment: thank you.Exactly.That was my concern and the answers that you are talking about , they don't mention how i free up memory used by program( maybe you did not read my question correctly or maybe did not get it ).

Comment: Or maybe you didn't express it adequately, and definitely you didn't read the answers as they were provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just delete it. The part that deletes the children of a node should be in the destructor of the node class, not outside. If you don't put it there, deletion isn't recursive, so you will leak grandchild nodes and their subtrees.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get really technical and practice your C++ 11 I would suggest using smart pointers. Just to be clear I would put all destruction mechanisms to the destructor but smart pointers are a great thing to c++ so as practice you should use them.

So you should declare something like this:

```
//don't forget to #include<memory>
std::unique_ptr<int> NstateAction;
//don't use vectors as arrays, if the standard library has an alternatve you should use it
std::vector<unique_ptr<int>> child;
std::unique_ptr<double> QValue;
```

Smart pointers are pointers that automatically release memory when they go out of scope so this should do the trick.

Now using smart pointers is a bit tricky but here is a question that will help:

[c++ - How can i initialize a smart point using a naked new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21525283/c-how-can-i-initialize-a-smart-point-using-a-naked-new)

Just go to the answers.